# How to write a ruby regex that removes characters only at first and last positions?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a log file, most lines are quoted at first and last character, like:

```
 "2010-09-09,13:33,"user logoff",0"
```

What's the ruby regex to remove the head and tail quotation marks? so the result string looks like:

```
 2010-09-09,13:33,"user logoff",0
```

Comment: @Kobi, that's supposed to be an error, to be handled by another script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
str.gsub /^"|"$/, ''
```

Answer (score 3):

Or without regular expressions:

```
string[1...-1]
```

Comment: But he wrote "*most* lines are quoted", so he doesn't always want to strip the first and last characters.

Comment: I see. Then the regexp is the right approach, missed that one.

Comment: @Chubas It still helped me a lot right now. So thanks for your wrong answer :)